# Passing enum to xml using VB.Net

Tags: xml, vb.net, soap, enums

am trying to pass enum value to xml parameter as shown below :

```
DoBook.CommitLevel = com.roomsxmldemo.EnumCommitLevel.prepare
```

or

```
 Dim c As New com.roomsxmldemo.EnumCommitLevel

        c = com.roomsxmldemo.EnumCommitLevel.prepare
        DoBook.CommitLevel = c
```

But am getting the following error :

TAN.WebServices.XML.TANSoapException: [442719/3] Required parameter 'CommitLevel' was not found in the request.

---> TAN.WebServices.XML.MissingParameterException: Required parameter 'CommitLevel' was not found in the request.

at TAN.WebServices.XML.Service.BookingCreate(Request xiRequest)
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at TAN.WebServices.XML.Service.HandleException(Context xiContext, Exception xiException)
  at TAN.WebServices.XML.Service.BookingCreate(Request xiRequest)

Description for the parameter as stated in the API

Data Type : Enum
Details : Two-valued text enumeration:
prepare – perform a dry-run booking, verifying all details such as prices and cancellation fees, as much as possible and obtaining hotel alert information, etc.
confirm – go ahead and create the booking

Sample from the company

```
 <CommitLevel xmlns="http://www.reservwire.com/namespace/WebServices/Xml">prepare</CommitLevel>
```

Comment: You are trying ... and problem is? Please add a bit more code (but not too much :D) and specify what is not going as you are expecting.

Comment: I have added more info IvanH